# How can i overcome fatal repository not found error

Tags: git, github, git-repo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lgxo.png)

I am trying to create a new repository from my system gitbash.
But a fatal error has came and not able to create a new repository as it says about my old repository which I have made but deleted from github repository as I have to make some changes.

please guide me to overcome this problem.
folder arrangement

```
>scorekeeper
   >.vscode
   > node_modules
   >public
   >src
   >.gitignore
   >package
   >package-lock
   >README.md
```

Comment: just run `git init`  in the scorekeeper folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify that the remote was successfully removed or see what remotes are in the repository, use the git remote command to list the remote connections:

```
git remote -v
```

The output will look something like this:

```
origin  https://github.com/user/repo_name.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user/repo_name.git (push)
```

What the `git remote rm` command does is removing the entries about the remote repository from the `.git/config` file.

You can also remove the remote by editing the .git/config file using your text editor. However, it is recommended to use the `git remote rm` command.

If the remote you are trying to remove doesn’t exist, Git will print an error message:
`fatal: No such remote: '<remote-name>'`

Therefore, Use the `git remote rm <remote-name>` command to remove a remote from a repository.

If you really want to remove all of the repositories, leaving only the working directory then it should be as simple as this.
`rm -rf .git`

Comment: thanks..for the valuable suggestion it works as my all earlier repository get removed now and can create a new repo

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the .git folder in your repo which is hidden btw and open the config file. You will see a url just copy and past your new github repo url there  and you are good to go.
If you do not want all your previous commits then you can delete the .git folder and try from scratch

Comment: I tried this but as old repo is deleted from github it is showing this message .  No source repositories were detected at https://github.com/vivek07542/scorekeeper_classbased.git. Please check the URL and try again.

Comment: There is no github repo with the link provided in comment. Can you check again